# c# Block access to file after a timer

Tags: c#, file, interrupt, streamwriter

I need to write a file that is located on a remote directory. I need to create a log application: every time an error occurs, I want to access this remote file and write a line. But if the remote directory is not available, I don't care. I simply want the main application keep running.

Usually accessing this remote directory takes 1 second. If the WriteLine method takes more than 1 second, I want to block it.

I tried with a try catch but then the entire application is blocked for a long time. I need to interrupt this attempt to write sooner.

This is the main code used to write on the txt file:

```
try 
{           
    string TargetFile = "F:\\file.txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(TargetFile))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("LOG: an error occured\n");
        sw.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Maybe by running the write operation inside a separate thread? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried it with asynchronous method? I heard it works great for IO operation such as this one. refer to : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137902(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I suggest you should use background jobs like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), so if the file is being used by another process you can reschedule the job.

Comment: But the probability that another process uses the file is very low .. that's why I don't care if the remote directory is not accessible, if one time I don't save the LOG is not a big problem. I simply don't want that the main application get stacked for that reason ..

Comment: Windows supports IO cancellation, but this is not exposed by .NET (so one option is P/Invoke). The other option would be be queue to the thread pool (but note this could lead to log messages out of order). I would look at the latter for your case (it seems your diagnostic logging is low importance, which seems odd to me: normally one logs to help fix problems, it will be useless for that if it is unreliable).

Comment: I suggest you should use a ready to use logging library, like log4net. It has solved many problems like yours a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) do not throw inside catch block

2) use managed threads to speed up the process and increase performance

If you are using .Net 4.5 and above the block i have written below will help. Just add this in your program

using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
var errorWriter =  Task.Run(() => 

        {
            try
            {
                string TargetFile = "F:\\file.txt";
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(TargetFile))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("LOG: an error occured\n");
                    sw.Close();
                    return "success";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;

              //  throw; _________________ don't throw here 
            }

        });
```